# Proving $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0}f(x^n) $

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0}f(x^n) $$ where $n$ is odd !
I'm new to delta epsilons.

I want to learn this and not just regurgitate it when needed.

Hints to tackle this would be appreciated.

Comment: lhs is defn delta epsilon but rhs has the x^n term in between

Comment: When $x^n$ is very small is precisely where $x$ is very small.

Comment: put how do i prove that though

Answer (score 2):

To reduce confusion, I'd prefer to use different variable names in the two limits.
First of all, be more precise about exactly what is to be proven.  There are really two parts:

1) If $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = L$ (i.e. exists and is equal to a real number $L$), then $\lim_{t \to 0} f(t^n)$ also exists and is equal to $L$.

2) If $\lim_{t \to 0} f(t^n) = L$ (i.e. exists and is equal to a real number $L$), then $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ also exists and is equal to $L$.

$\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = L$ means for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $|x| < \delta$, $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

$\lim_{t \to 0} f(t^n) = L$ means for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\eta > 0$ such that whenever $|t| < \eta$, $|f(t^n) - L| < \epsilon$.

Now notice that there's a precise correspondence between these: writing 
$x = t^n$, $|x| < \delta$ if and only if $|t| < \delta^{1/n}$.

Comment: This is way too advanced for me i dont understand it! For example lets do a proof where n =3

Comment: ive only looked at proofs using delta epsilon only not Its vairients